How is revalidateTag in Next Js supposed to be used?
I'm trying to understand how revalidateTag work. I'm used to Tanstack, where you from anywhere in the application can invalidate a cache and tanstack will refresh data associated with that tag. I'm using revalidateTag in the same manor and it works locally is I thought.
But when I deploy the application it does not work as I think, it returns initalData no matter what.
I have a serveraction that is being called after a user saves some answer, what I want is to update a component inside of my header that check if the user have answered the question.
Where I intally get the data(ServerSide):
const [configuration, customer, user] = await Promise.all([
        GET<Configuration>('GetConfiguration'),
        GET<Customer>('GetCustomer'),
        GET<User>('GetUser', 'User'),
    ]);

Then I pass the data to a component:
<HeaderRightContent
                canAnswerQuestion={user?.canAnswerQuestion || false}
                customerName={customer?.Name}>

Consuming component (Simplyfied):
export function AnswerButton({ canAnswerQuestion}: { canAnswerQuestion: boolean }) { 
return (
                {canAnswerDailyQuestion ? (
                    <Button onPress={() => openModal}>
                        Answer
                    </Button>
                ) : (<div>Done<div>)}
}

ServerAction:
'use server';

import { POST } from '@/utils/api';
import { Answer } from '../types';
import { revalidateTag } from 'next/cache';

export async function postAnswer(data: Answer) {
    let success = false;
    try {
        const response = await POST('SaveAnswer', JSON.stringify(data));
        success = response.Success;
        revalidateTag('User');
        return success;
    } catch {}
    return success;
}

fetch util. function:
export async function GET<T>(
    endpoint: string,
    cacheTag?: string,
    cache: RequestCache | undefined = 'force-cache'
): Promise<T | null | undefined> {
    const neededCookies = cookies().toString();

    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.PATH_INTERNAL}${endpoint}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        cache,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Cookie: neededCookies || '',
        },
        redirect: 'manual',
        ...(cacheTag && { next: { tags: [cacheTag] } }),
    });

    if (res.status >= 300 && res.status < 400) permanentRedirect(redirectLoginUrl);

    try {
        return await res.json();
    } catch (err) {
        return null;
    }
}
export async function POST(endpoint: string, data?: string) {
    const neededCookies = cookies().toString();
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.PATH_INTERNAL}${endpoint}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Cookie: neededCookies || '',
        },
        body: data,
        redirect: 'manual',
    });

    if (res.status >= 300 && res.status < 400) permanentRedirect(redirectLoginUrl);

    try {
        return await res.json();
    } catch (err) {
        return null;
    }
}

What I would expect is nextjs to refecth data related to the tag and re-render affected components. But it does not. What I'm doing wrong here?

I think the way how you use cacheTag is wrong here
export async function GET<T>(
    endpoint: string,
    cacheTag?: string,
    cache: RequestCache | undefined = 'force-cache'
): Promise<T | null | undefined> {}

Here are the Parameters of the Route Handler functions:

request (optional)
The request object is a NextRequest object, which is an extension of
the Web Request API. NextRequest gives you further control over the
incoming request, including easily accessing cookies and an extended,
parsed, URL object nextUrl.
context (optional)
type Params = {
  team: string
}
 
export async function GET(request: Request, context: { params: Params }) {
  const team = context.params.team // '1'
}

// Define params type according to your route parameters (see table
below)

I do not think that you are passing cacheTag to the function when fetching data.

That's correct and I'm using it with fetch. I did not include the POST method because it's just a fetch utillity. But I have updated the question now.

updated the answer. can you console.log(cacheTag) in  GET handler

Thx for the response I will check it!

Sry for late response.. but I logged it and I get the cacheTag. And as I wrote in the question. Locally it works as it should.
